# Como buscar a tupla mais atualizada no postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Amigos.
Estou tendo dificuldades em recuperar a quilometragem mais atual de um veículo quando o mesmo chega na empresa. A identificação da tupla é pela a data de chegada do veículo na empresa.
No momento eu tenho o seguinte `SQL`:

```
select relatorio_viagem_veiculo.referencia_veiculo, MAX(relatorio_viagem.data_chegada) from relatorio_viagem inner join relatorio_viagem_veiculo on( relatorio_viagem.id_relatorio_viagem = relatorio_viagem_veiculo.id_relatorio_viagem ) where relatorio_viagem_veiculo.referencia_veiculo = '246' and            relatorio_viagem.data_saida between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-31' group by   relatorio_viagem_veiculo.referencia_veiculo, relatorio_viagem.data_chegadaorder by relatorio_viagem.data_chegada desc;
```

E me retorna o seguinte resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que me retornasse o registro mais atual, ou seja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter explicado bem o que eu desejo. Desde já eu agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova o campo `data_chegada` do `group by`, dessa maneira será retornada a referência de cada veículo e a data máxima.

```
SELECT
    relatorio_viagem_veiculo.referencia_veiculo,
    max(relatorio_viagem.data_chegada)
FROM relatorio_viagem
    INNER JOIN relatorio_viagem_veiculo 
        ON (relatorio_viagem.id_relatorio_viagem = relatorio_viagem_veiculo.id_relatorio_viagem)
WHERE
    relatorio_viagem_veiculo.referencia_veiculo = '246'
    AND relatorio_viagem.data_saida BETWEEN '2017-03-01'
    AND '2017-03-31'
GROUP BY
    relatorio_viagem_veiculo.referencia_veiculo
ORDER BY
    2 DESC;
```

Comment: ERRO:  coluna "relatorio_viagem.data_chegada" deve aparecer na cláusula GROUP BY ou ser utilizada em uma função de agregação
LINE 14:     relatorio_viagem.data_chegada DESC;

Comment: @BrunoDuarte, o erro deve ser por causa do `order by`, eu editei a minha resposta, tenta novamente com o novo código, com a referência ao índice 2.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!